# Javascript base class constructor run with subclass (overridden) property

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, inheritance

I am having this problem with subclasses overriding class property in JS. I think the behavior in OOP is what I want, but I wish to achieve the same in JS.

```js
class Base {
   constructor () {
       console.log(this.a)
   }
}

class Child extends Base {
    a = 1
}

new Child()

// undefined, but I expect (want) 1
```

How do I modify my code to log `1`?

Example in Python, that works:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.a)
        
class Child(Base):
    a = 1
    
Child()

# 1 -> desirable
```

Comment: May have found a good anwser https://javascript.info/class-inheritance#overriding-class-fields-a-tricky-note

Comment: It's a matter of timing. You can not access a property before it is declared, that's why you get `undefined`. And you can not change the execution order, because you can not access `this` in a derived constructor before `super()` is called. So to solve this, you'd need to be more specific on what exactly it is you want to do in your base-class, to find a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` output is expected behavior. You haven't defined the property `a` in the base class so it is just natural that base class constructor outputs `undefined` in the console.

```js
class Base {
   constructor () {
       console.log('Base constructor', this.a) // outputs undefined
   }
}

class Child extends Base {
    a = 1

   constructor () {
      super();
      console.log('Child constructor', this.a); // outputs 1
   }
}

new Child()
```

**UPDATE**

In Python, `__init__` function is not a real constructor. Constructor is `__new__`.

Comment: Not exactly. If you add a method to the base-class and call that method after construction, then the base-class has full access to all properties on that instance (by design). JS has just recently gotten [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields). Before that, **every property** was public *(closures are a seperate topic)*. The issue is where the `i=1` is executed. It's basically inlined like this: `super(); this.i = 1; console.log('Child constructor', this.a);`. So it's not a matter of privacy but of timing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the thing is, i have a lot of Childs and dont want to write up a separate constructor in all of them. Would be interested to know if there is any quick hacks I can do

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
class Base {
   constructor () {
       console.log(this.a)
   }
}

class Child extends Base {
    get a () { return 1 }
}

new Child()
```